# How to make hair particles point upward?

Tags: mesh, particles, hair

I want to make hair particles point in an upward direction only, not in the direction according to emitter mesh.

[image]

Just wanted to show the final render, environment bit dull though.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It should work the same way in 2.7: You need to enable the *Advanced* option, then the *Rotation* option, and choose *Orientation Axis > Global Z* (or whatever orientation you want, you may need to rotate your particle object in *Edit* mode to align it with the axis you want):

[image]

Comment: now i know why your hair is always in good shape!! :D

Comment: not so much unfortunately  :/

Comment: Just increase number in the children tab…‍♂️

Comment: I hope geometry node shampoo will save my hair

Comment: Important: increase density in point/hair distribute node ‍♂️